# How to use @Qualifier for different session factory in hibernate?

Tags: database, hibernate, session, sessionfactory

how the @Qualifier Annotation use on the method that inject the multiple  sessionFactory. and how we will maintain the different session factory for different database connection.

Comment: can anybody help me on this.

Comment: what is the best approach for this ?

Comment: public class Customer {

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("personA")
 private Person person;
 
}

Answer (score 0):

To fix above problem, you have to define @Qualifier to tell Spring about which bean should autowired.
@shivani

public class Customer
 {

```
@Autowired
**@Qualifier("personA")**
private Person person;

}
```

[link](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/)